# Rename old name in multiple folders to new name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA in Microsoft excel for the first time. I have to change old names in different folders to new name.

```
OldName     path                    NewName     
Dayz.xls    C:\Users\Staffs\Dayz\   DayzStaff.xls
Mary.xls    C:\Users\Staffs\Mary\   MaryStaff.xls
```

Up to 100 records

I tried below code. But how to loop in VBA?. Please help me to solve this.

```
oldfilename = "C:\Users\Staffs\Dayz\Dayz.xls"
newfilename = "C:\Users\Staffs\Dayz\DayzStaff.xls"
Name oldfilename As newfilename
```

Comment: Do you just need to add `Staff` onto the old file name? Also, although they're in different folders are they all in `C:\Users\Staffs` as the top folder and then a folder (Manager name?) containing a single Excel file.

Comment: yes.. just concatenate it with staff. all are in C:\Users\Staffs. But in different folders.. Dayz, Mary etc are folders in Staff.I have folder names in a excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.  It will get all the Excel file names from the `Staffs` folder and append `Staff` to the end of the name.  This will take anything with an extension starting as 'xls'.

```
Public Sub RenameFiles()

    Dim vFiles As Variant
    Dim vFile As Variant

    'Get all file names of XLS files from C:\Users\Staffs & subfolders.
    vFiles = EnumerateFiles("C:\Users\Staffs\", "xls*")

    'Cycle through each name.
    For Each vFile In vFiles
        'Take everything to the left of the last . add "staff" and add the extension back on.
        'If they're all the same file type (xls or xlsx) then you can remove the
        'MID command and just type use xls.
        Name vFile As Left(vFile, InStrRev(vFile, ".") - 1) & " Staff" & Mid(vFile, InStrRev(vFile, "."))
    Next vFile

End Sub

Public Function EnumerateFiles(sDirectory As String, _
            Optional sFileSpec As String = "*", _
            Optional InclSubFolders As Boolean = True) As Variant

    EnumerateFiles = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec _
        ("CMD /C DIR """ & sDirectory & "*." & sFileSpec & """ " & _
        IIf(InclSubFolders, "/S ", "") & "/B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a range on the worksheet that has a list of the folders and the XLSX is named as the folder is (as per your example above) then this would do the trick:

```
rootfldr = "C:\Users\Staffs\"
For Each fldrname In Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A100").Value ' the range of the list
    oldfilename = rootfldr & fldrname & "\" & fldrname & ".xlsx"
    newfilename rootfldr & fldrname & "\" & fldrname & "Staff.xlsx"
    Name oldfilename As newfilename
Next
```